# .NET version of HTML Tidy?

Tags: c#, .net, tidy, htmltidy

Does anyone know if there's a native port of HTML Tidy available for .NET? In Sourceforge, there's a TidyNet project - which hasn't been updated since 2005 and seems like a wrapper only. Java port seems to exist as recent JTidy project.

HTML Tidy project page:
http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the Tidy.NET hasn't been updated in a while.

An alternative is [TidyForNet](http://tidyfornet.sourceforge.net/) Links on that page to the source code in SVN.

> "This wrapper is based upon a wrapper
>   provided by Adrian Bateman
>
> The key advantage of this .NET and
>   Wrapper is that it directly binds into
>   the original HTML Tidy library, which
>   is written in C. It then exposes a
>   .NET class that can be consumed by any
>   .NET application. By directly binding
>   to the original HTML Tidy sources,
>   incorporating updates in the original
>   HTML Tidy program is merely a matter
>   of updating source files.
>
> However, due to the lack of C++.NET
>   support on the Linux platform, the
>   wrapper itself has been rewritten in
>   C# and now uses P/Invoke calls to
>   access the HTML Tidy library. HTML
>   Tidy itself, of course, is not
>   re-written in C#, and at all times the
>   latest version can be obtained by
>   merely updating the sources."