# Using HTML Tidy with ASP.NET Tags

Tags: asp.net, html, htmltidy

I've discovered a very nice tool for cleaning up a mess of HTML in a project I have inherited:

- **HTML Tidy** at http://infohound.net/tidy/

Basically, I can paste in my HTML, click the *Tidy* button, and it cleans everything up.

However, my project is an **ASP.NET** web site, and HTML Tidy does not know what an `asp` tag is.

Therefore, by default, it simply removes it.

Ouch! Suddenly, nothing works because I have no controls on my form.

Looking at the Help and going into Advanced features, I set the **Output** format to `Side by Side Diff`, which will display the `asp` tags, is something, but now the two halves do not appear to be very related.

Is there a way, using the web interface, that I can get HTML Tidy to output the items it does not understand?

If not, is there another tidy tool for ASP.NET pages that will not cut out all of my `asp` tags?

The closest question I found related to this was [.NET version of HTML Tidy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824745/net-version-of-html-tidy), but there could be better answers that did not pull up in my search.

Comment: I just tried the http://validator.w3.org HTML Tidy with ASP.NET, it also got rid of my tags. :{

Comment: CTRL+K CTRL-D does a good job of formatting the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best editor is to just configure all of the very elaborate settings from within Visual Studio's HTML Text Editor Options.

[image: VS2010 HTML Text Editor Options]

Answer (score 0):

Tidy assumes you want to output valid HTML, so it doesn't play nice with ASP.NET server side tags. If you're just looking for something to indent your html, try http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier.

Comment: It keeps getting to 73%, then it just stops. It never gives me an output.